# Open URL in Parent WIndow

Tags: javascript, url, window, reload

I am attempting to open a URL in a parent window once a page is reloaded. Currently, it is just reloading the parent window. How do I get it to reload a URL instead of the parent page?

Here is the code:

EDIT: Here is the complete code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title></title>
<style type="text/css">
.left_border_right_cell {
    border-left-width: 1px;
    border-left-style: solid;
    border-left-color: #999;
}
.facebook_login_hd1 {
    font-family: Verdana;
    font-size: 14pt;
    color: #333;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin-left: 15px;
}
.facebook_body_txt {
    font-family: Verdana;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: normal;
    color: #333;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin-left: 15px;
}
.login_hdr_text_hd2 {
    font-family: Verdana;
    font-size: 14pt;
    color: #900;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin-left: 15px;
}
.submit_button {
    font-family: Verdana;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #FFF;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: #900;
    border: 1px solid #900;
    margin-left: 15px;
}
.facebook_f12media_bld {
    font-family: Verdana;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #900;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.field_properties {
    font-family: Verdana;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: normal;
    color: #900;
    text-decoration: none;
    border: 1px solid #900;
}
.reset_button {
    font-family: Verdana;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #900;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: #FFF;
    border: 1px solid #900;
}
.login_field_label {
    font-family: Verdana;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #333;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin-left: 15px;
}
.login_forgot_password {
    font-family: Verdana;
    font-size: 10px;
    font-weight: normal;
    color: #900;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin-left: 15px;
    margin-top: 1px;
    margin-bottom: 1px;
    padding: 0px;
}
</style>

<script language="text/javascript">
function close_reload()
{

    parent.parent.window.location.reload();parent.parent.GB_hide();

}
</script>
</head>

<body onload="setTimeout('parent.parent.window.location.replace('http://www.f12media.com/account.php');parent.parent.GB_hide();', 5000)" onunload="parent.parent.window.location.reload();parent.parent.GB_hide();">



<table width="683" height="298" border="0">
  <tr>
    <td height="312" valign="top"><p class="facebook_login_hd1">Welcome to F12 MEDIA&#8482; </p>
  <p class="facebook_body_txt">You are now connected with <span class="facebook_f12media_bld">F12 MEDIA</span>.</p>
  </p>
  <p class="login_hdr_text_hd2">&nbsp;</p>
      <form id="login_sign_fm" name="login_sign_fm" method="post" action="">
</form>      <p class="login_hdr_text_hd2">&nbsp;</p></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 6):

If you want it to load a specific URL, set that URL, don't call reload().

```
window.parent.parent.window.location = "http://whatever.com/index.html";
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, wanting to open a specific URL on a parent window from a popup without having to reload the page. Since mine is a php I didn't want to have the alert when reloading the page so opening it again will work as the results will refresh themselves when loading.

I used the following code (on the child window) to do so:

```
window.opener.location = "https://www.whateverURLYouWant.com/";
```

This will load whatever URL you want on your parent window.

I hope this help future same questions.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try `.replace(url)` instead of `.reload()`. And while you're at it, you might want to create a simple function for this.

```
function loadParent(url) {
  parent.parent.window.location.replace(url);
  parent.parent.GB_hide();
}

<body onload="setTimeout('loadParent(\"http://cnn.com\")', 5000)" 
      onunload="loadParent('http://cnn.com');">
```

Comment: I may have failed to mention that this page is opened in greybox pop up window.

Comment: Did you try just `parent.window` (instead of `parent.parent.window`)?

Comment: Your code worked but it doesn't automatically close the window as I would like it to function like it did before. How do we close the window automatically after a set amount of time?

Answer (score 1):

It's Simple Just Put The Following:

```
self.opener.location.replace(url,"_self");
alwaysLowered = true; // Bring the Parent window in front & hide the current one
```

This will open url in the parent window.

Tell me if it didn't work.